# Origen del uso de "cromo" para significar "estampa coleccionable"

Tags: vocabulario, historia

Al menos en España, un **cromo** es una pequeña estampa con texto y dibujos o fotos, normalmente destinada a ser coleccionada, intercambiada o usada por niños para jugar; lo que en inglés sería una ***trading card***.

Como no le veía mucha relación con el [metal cromo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BL1dx7W), iba a preguntar por el origen de la palabra en sí, pero leo en el DLE:

> **[cromo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BL2nfP8)**
>   Acort. de *cromolitografía*.

La verdad, *cromolitografía* me parece una palabra increíblemente específica y técnica; no entiendo cómo pudo pasar al habla común, existiendo otras como "carta" o "naipe" con siglos de uso para conceptos muy similares.
Además, *cromolitografía* tiene género femenino, pero no se dice "una cromo": se usa en masculino, "un cromo" (contrario a acortamientos similares como "una foto"). Incluso hay modismos como "estar hecho un cromo" que hacen uso de la palabra.

¿De dónde viene "un cromo" como acortamiento de "una cromolitografía", y cómo llegó a popularizarse su uso en lugar de "carta" o "naipe" o similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesar de que esa acepción de *cromo* hace referencia a una *cromolitografía*, el nombre "cromo" ya existía desde antes en el lenguaje, lo que marca la diferencia entre este caso y otros como "una foto" (por "fotografía"; y aunque "foto" ya existía de antes, en el siglo XIX la palabra llevaba tiempo en desuso) o "una promo" (por "promoción"). Al ser "cromo" una palabra masculina, se debió de quedar con ese género cuando se acortó, dado que al decir "cromo" la gente hacía referencia al elemento usado, más que a la técnica de reproducción. Además, el elemento cromo no llevaba mucho tiempo descubierto, por lo que a principios del siglo XIX constituía una novedad.

Vemos ejemplos (negritas mías) de la palabra siendo usada ya en el siglo XIX en el CORDE:

> *Traía a la niña diariamente alguna baratija, para ella desconocida hasta entonces, ya **un cromo**, ya una fotografía, ya lindas flores, ya números de periódicos ilustrados, ya novelas de Fernán Caballero o de Alarcón [...].*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, "Un viaje de novios", 1881 (España).

Otros en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> *Aludimos á la* Historia de la Virgen María *que acaba de salir de las prensas del señor Martínez con un lujo desconocido hasta ahora en las publicaciones españolas, con láminas que por sí solas bastarán á hacer interesante esta obra, con **un cromo** precioso que sirve de portada y con orlas de oro en todas las caras, composición notable que se distingue por el buen gusto de su dibujo, por los atributos que encierra y por el bellísimo efecto que causa su conjunto.*
>
> El Mundo pintoresco. 8/5/1859, n.º 19, página 8.

Aunque no fue hasta 1884 que la palabra *cromo* entró en el DLE, como equivalente a la segunda acepción de *cromolitografía*: "estampa obtenida por medio de este arte".

No he encontrado ningún resultado de *cromo* siendo usado en femenino, que indique que en algún momento se intentara usar realmente como acortamiento de *cromolitografía*. Y eso que la palabra se escribía como *cromo-litografía* allá por el siglo XIX (se encuentran muchos casos en la hemeroteca), lo que habría facilitado el usarla simplemente como "una cromo". De ahí que deduzca que al decir "un cromo" la gente tuviera en mente el elemento y no la técnica de reproducción.

Otra opción, como bien has comentado, es que la expresión "un cromo" sea en realidad un acortamiento de "un dibujo cromolitográfico", aunque en el CORDE solo se encuentra un caso:

> *La dificultad del **dibujo cromolitográfico** no estriba solamente en su ejecución material sino tambien en el conocimiento de los efectos que debe producir la impresión por la combinación de colores [...].*
>
> Justo Zapater y Jareño, José García Alcaraz, "Manual de Litografía", 1878 (España).

Aunque de nuevo hay algunos más en la hemeroteca:

> *Si como hacen suponer los acontecimientos, continúa Paris algún tiempo mas en incomunicación, haremos cuanto se pueda por confeccionar algún **dibujo cromolitográfico** para cañamazo ó alguna otra labor de colores [...].*
>
> La Guirnalda (Madrid). 1/5/1871, página 2.

Y uno que he encontrado de "cuadro cromolitográfico" en NGram que es incluso anterior al primer ejemplo de "un cromo", lo que daría más validez a esta teoría:

> *El **cuadro cromolitográfico** (núm. 57), de Monsieur Marquier, llamó mucho la atencion de los inteligentes, tanto por la belleza y variedad de los colores, como por la exactitud con que están aplicados con diferentes piedras [...].*
>
> Memoria de la Real Sociedad Económica de La Habana, 1848 (Cuba).

Comment: @walen es muy probable. He comentado esa opción en mi respuesta, aunque con matices.

Comment: @walen nada, olvida los matices.